# Data Management Issue - How to manage retrieved data from mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, database, data-manipulation, data-management

I am developing a game(c#) with database(mysql) and web service(php) to retrieving the data. The issue is the data management. There is a table on database with the name of items and it has some columns like id, item_name, item_description, item_prop, update_date, ownerId. I added 70 items to this table manually. The users can also add some items to this table or they can update the items they have already added in the game. My purpose is retrieving the whole affected rows of the table when the user is first logged in and save it as a json file in the game folder. After, read that file to fill the game environment with those items.

I try a way to achieve this. Firstly, i hold an updateDate variable in the game which is past like "1990-05-10 21:15:43". Second, i send this variable to the webservice as `'$lastUpdateDate';` and make a query according to that variable at the database. `select * from channels where update_date >= '$lastUpdateDate';` and write these rows in a json file as items.json. after that make a second query to retrieve the time and refresh the updateDate variable in the game. `select select now() as 'Result';`. In this way user would not have to get the whole table and write in json file every login process. So, it would be good for the performance and the internet usage. The problem occurs when the users update an item which is already added before. I can see the updated item, too with the first query, but I wrote it in json file twice in this way.

**php code part of the getItems of my loginuser.php :**

```
<?php
include './function.php';
// CONNECTIONS =========================================================
$host = "localhost"; //put your host here
$user = "root"; //in general is root
$password = ""; //use your password here
$dbname = "yourDataBaseName"; //your database
$phpHash = "yourHashCode"; // same code in here as in your Unity game

mysql_connect($host, $user, $password) or die("Cant connect into database");
mysql_select_db($dbname)or die("Cant connect into database");

$op = anti_injection_register($_REQUEST["op"]);
$unityHash = anti_injection_register($_REQUEST["myform_hash"]);

if ($unityHash == $phpHash)
{
    if($op == "getItems")
    {
        $lastUpdateDate = anti_injection_login($_POST["updateDate"]);
        if(!$lastUpdateDate)
        {
            echo "Empty";
        }
        else
        {
            $q = "select * from items where update_date >= '$lastUpdateDate';";
            $rs = mysql_query($q);
            if (!$rs) 
            {
                echo "Could not successfully run query ($q) from DB: " . mysql_error();
                exit;
            }
            if (mysql_num_rows($rs) == 0) 
            {
                echo "No rows found, nothing to print so am exiting";
                exit;
            }
            $arr = array();
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($rs)) 
            {
                $arr = $row;
            }
            echo json_encode($arr);         
        }
        mysql_close();
    }
}
?>
```

So, how can i solve this problem? Or do you have any better idea for this approach. Help would be much appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/fHKuMOE.png

Comment: The link is not opening. @Martin

Comment: It's a picture, outlining the risk area of data on a client machine (ie not your server)

Comment: This is a wide topic, and it's a wide topic because Games in general have appauling security and data-authenticity systems, and the people who design games are often not well versed in data-security. Unfortunately because it is such a broad topic, Stack Overflow users are quick to close the question(s) rather than try and present approaches to answering them. This comes across (to me at least) somewhat like ignoring the elephant in the room, while concentrating on the mouse...

Comment: The image outlines the simple concept that you should not trust anything that didn't come from your own machine. So client machines hosting a client copy of a game can run *anything*. So from this point of view, online gaming (as in, a game that communicates with a server, in any way) should be treated rather like online banking, and data should be checked, rechecked and always assumed to be untrusted.

Comment: [This blog post](https://futrworld.blogspot.co.uk/2017/01/breaking-verified-game-scores-in-unity.html) could prove some valuable insights into the scale of the problem you are facing.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and the blog post opened up my horizon :) But i am not sure that i got your point. Do you mean i should not arrange the items.json file repeatedly in the running game? Should i just get the whole table for every login process? If so, it would occurs some performance issues. Because the table will have lots of rows in time. How can i manage it?

Comment: You have to have a trade off between performance issues and security issues, for a maximum security illustration; everything that is done on the local game should be copied-to and verified-from the remote server running a copy-instance of the game. Also I would suggest while JSON is easy to use, it is very common so trivial for others to manipulate, if they choose too.

Comment: Ok, you are right. But the performance issue will be unacceptable, i think. Lets think about that table will reach 2 MB size in time, this means every user will retrieve this size of data for every login requests. Also, if i will want to make same requests again and again to the refresh the items in the running game (let say at 15 second intervals). It means huge data transactions :) and will cause high latency. I think there should be a right way to do my purpose, but i could not figure out how.

Comment: No, you do not need to download the whole table, only the rows that relate to that user, so you need to define an authentication key (such as a hash of the access time + access username) and only grab the MySQL data relating to that user. Also you can grab data only set within a certain time frame as well....

Comment: Also **VERY IMPORTANT** stop using `mysql_` PHP functions, they are *Deprecated*, instead you will need to explore `mysqli_` functions (which are very similar syntax but more secure) or possibly `PDO`

Comment: thank you for your warning, i will fix them. But i can not understand your comment before :) Actually, i was doing the same thing without any hashcode as you told (is this hashcode something like session cookie?, if so i could not do this within the unity3d). Whole items table rows are related to all users and it must be stored in their game folder up to date.

Comment: I possibly misunderstand what data you need on the *local* game? Possibly edit your question to make it clearer which rows of the database will be needed to display the correct output to the player. Cheers

Comment: Also 2Mb of text data in MySQL is thousands of rows of info. That's a lot.

Comment: Whole table rows info must be up to date in the users local game. Also, each user can add or update a row in that table. I try to make this.
Yes i think there will be thousand of table. So, that table will expand much. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: I would suggest you take your original question and break it into component parts, and then rewrite your question (or start a new one) to ask just one part of this overall topic, so you can ask 5-6 *specific* questions on StackOverflow to get answers to specific aspects of your problem. Good luck with it!